# Using 100% height within an element without a height property

Tags: html, css

I have found that when using `height: 100%` on an element inside of a `div`, it does not work unless the `div` containing it is fixed height.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jE3Xf/3/).

HTML

```
<div id='header' class='bodyRect'>
    <div id='welcome'>
        <h1>This is a welcome message</h1>
        <p>Welcome to this website.</p>
        <p>It is websitey.</p>
        <p>Click <a id='toggle' href='#'>here</a> to toggle fixed vs 100% height to see the problem.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='logo'></div>
    <span class='clearfix'></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.bodyRect {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#welcome {
    width: 70%; float: left
}
#logo {
    width: 30%; float: right;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

JS (for testing; it toggles between fixed and non-fixed height so you can see the problem)

```
var fixedHeight = false
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    fixedHeight = !fixedHeight
    var newHeight = fixedHeight ? '500px' : '100%'
    alert('height is now ' + newHeight)
    document.getElementById('logo').style.height = newHeight
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle and in this code, the child `div` will only expand to fill the parent `div` if the parent `div` has a fixed `height` attribute.

However, I don't want to use a fixed height. I want the height of the parent `div` to be able to change. How can I make my child `div` expand to fill the parent without using a fixed height on the parent?

Comment: That's a circular calculation.  The child div is based on the height of the parent, which is based on the height of the child, which is based on the height of the parent, which is....

Comment: So what's your ultimate goal?  Equal height columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish that is to take the child div out of the document flow.

Set the parent to `position:relative;` and the child to `position:absolute;`

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gePs/

Comment: However that won't work because I don't know the width of the child div.

Comment: The width doesn't matter, I just added it for illustration.  If you have content inside the child, you can omit the width and it'll expand to fit the content.  See http://jsfiddle.net/9gePs/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.childDiv{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

That will expand it to 100% in all directions providing the parent has a relative position.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the ideal answer you were looking for, but using some **jQuery**:

```
$(function(){
      var logo_height_percent = 100;  //<-- set the percent here
      $('#logo').height($('#header').height() * logo_height_percent/100);
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rHTVQ/)